# update a specific column in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my knowledge view is a virtual table, which contains rows and columns, just like a real table and use for view the data.

Is it possible to update a specific column in a view.

For Example:

```
update dbo.MyView
set [column1] = "some value"
where [column2] = "some value"
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't want to update views, unless the database has been designed for that purpose. In general, you want to update the tables are comprise the view.

In SQL Server, you can update a view under two circumstances.

The first is when the view is an *updatable* view. Such views have to have certain very specific conditions, which are described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx).

The second is when the view has an `instead of update` trigger on it. This is a trigger that (typically) updates the underlying tables.